# MonoTouch.Dialog: how to create RadioElement inside another RootElement?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have two `RootElement` elements boxed. See code. The deepest level is supposed to have tappable `StringElement` that allows selecting the current review. However, I'm getting a NULL reference error because of missing `RadioGroup`.
Is it possible with MT.Dialog?

```
Root = new RootElement ("Annotations")
{
  new Section ("Review")
  {
    // This element's caption is supposed to be whatever gets selected deep down.
    new RootElement("Reviews", new RadioGroup(0))
    {
      new Section("My Reviews")
      {
        new RootElement("Local profile")
       {
         new Section()
         {
           // Tapping this element should make "Local profile selected" appear as caption of the "Reviews" RootElement.
           new RadioElement("Activate", "Local profile selected")
         },
...more elements...
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify the radio group, like this:

```
new RootElement ("Local Profile", new RadioGroup (0)) {
    ....
}
```